# Latitude D830 spontaneous reboots

Tags: reboot

I have a Dell Latitude D830 that constantly re-boots.
Have tried countless remedies, any suggestions please?
Pulling my hair out! Thanks, Danny.

Comment: Anything interesting in event logs? How about bluescreens and minidumps?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you tried to clean or reinstall your OS. If you already did...

It may be related to a heating problem, try to monitor temperatures with speedfan to see if it goes higher than 90°C. In this case you should try a laptop cooler or you could clean the dust off fans and heatsinks. If you want to disassemble your DELL to remove the dust, read [the official service manual.](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/latd830/en/SM_EN/index.htm)

Else, if you got a bsod like Journeyman Geek suggested, chances are ram is to blame. Check your ram with memtest then replace the faulty ram stick. If its not the ram, could be the hard drive, [check the S.M.A.R.T health test of the drive](http://hddscan.com/).

Comment: Checking memory in a D830 is no fun because slot 1 is under the keyboard.

Comment: I had a D630 and you know, disassemble the palm-rest is not hard, plus the laptop has to be powered off when you do it so I don't see what is so unfunny with the keyboard ?

Comment: It's neither terrible nor particularly difficult, it's just not nearly as nice and easy as laptops where all RAM slots are behind a single access panel.  It's not the worst design I've worked on, but not the best either.